# $lookup aggregation for nested array ids

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have `Label`, `Conversations` and `Messages` models...

Label contains Conversations id's... I have used $lookup which works for conversation

```
const conversation = await Label.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5abcb74bb59afe4310c60266") } },
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'conversations',
        localField: 'conversations',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: "conversations"
      }
    }])
```

and gives output like

```
[{ 
    _id: 5abcb74bb59afe4310c60266,
    name: 'Archive',
    value: 'archive',
    user: 5abc93a85d3914318cc8d3d7,
    conversations: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    __v: 0 
}]
```

Now I have `messages` inside `conversations`

```
[{ 
    _id: 5abe07717a978c41b270b1bc,
    messages: [ 5abe07717a978c41b270b1bd ],
    members: [ 5abc93a85d3914318cc8d3d7, 5abc9467b7c99332f0a6813c ],
    __v: 0
}]
```

So how do I apply $lookup for the messages fields which is inside

**label -> conversations -> messasges**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use `$unwind` on `$conversations`. This will cause your `conversations` array to explode and you will now have as much documents as conversations in your hands.

Then you should do your `$lookup`, and (if wanted) `$group` to fallback on what you had before `$unwind`

```
const conversation = await Label.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5abcb74bb59afe4310c60266") } },
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'conversations',
        localField: 'conversations',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: "conversations"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$conversations" },
    {
        $lookup: {
        from: 'messages', 
        localField: 'conversations.messages',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'myMessages'
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Hi @Webvoid... above answer works for me... but conversations are  splitting... how do i apply `$group`